# operate disk with different character encoding

Tags: linux, centos

I have a disk in Chinese Simplified character encoding copied from Windows.

And now I installed centos7 with Chinese Traditional character encoding.

1 How could I mount this disk?

I use command 
ntfs-3g /dev/sdb /mnt/windows -o locale=zh_CN.GBK
but I still got messy filename then.

2 How could I copy these files?

I use command cp -r ,then 
it prints

cp -r  /mnt/7 /home/jl/文件/7
cp: 無法存取 ‘/mnt/7/20140206/\275̰\270/\261\270\277\316’: 不適用或不完整的多位元組字元或寬字元
cp: 無法存取 ‘/mnt/7/20140206/\275̰\270/֪ʶ\265\343’: 不適用或不完整的多位元組字元或寬字元
cp: 無法存取 ‘/mnt/7/20140206/\277Ƽ\274\273’: 不適用或不完整的多位元組字元或寬字元

You may not read this,it means cp couldn't execute because of unfit character(?)

This issue is caused by different path separator in OS obviously.

And I tried 
convmv -f gbk -t big5 -r --notest /home/jl/文件/7
but failed either.
[image]

Should I use scp to copy this dir?

Comment: Bad formatting. Don't post text as image. Disk doesn't have encoding. NTFS always encode filenames using UTF-16. "Chinese Simplified character" is not a name for encoding. Solution for your problem: Re-mount ntfs using utf-8 option instead of locale option and set your terminal emulator to use UTF-8 encoding. Also make sure you have UTF-8 locale in your environment.

Comment: If the data was encoded originally as UTF-16, mounting it as UTF-8 won't convert the encoding: it's still going to be UTF-16 encoded data.

Comment: @炸鱼薯条德里克 There are many character encodes as you know.I am not sure which one was taken in that Windows system.Is it cp 936?

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, you're dealing with different encoding protocols: Windows encodes in ***UTF-16***, whereas the default for Linux & OSX is ***UTF-8***.

So although you've set the encoding to ***UTF-8*** when mounting your pile of data in Linux, the data was encoded with ***UTF-16*** by Windows.

I suspect the filenames contain multi-byte characters that are not being read correctly in UTF-8. As a general rule, when working with bi-lingual staff I tell them to stick to non-accented characters in UTF-8 which are the first 128 characters) for filenames to avoid exactly this type of pain.

Differences in character encodings in filenames can cause grief restoring a TAR backup to a system with different encodings.

Anyhow, you can convert encodings with ICU: http://site.icu-project.org/.

HTH you out-